# Using C# for input and output to Python

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to use C# to read and write to a Python script.  I can successfully write to the script and get it run functions on my C# command.  But I cannot figure out how to also use RedirectStandardOutput with StreamReader to receive the results of the python code (either a return value or a write to screen statement); it just locks up the program.

C# Code:

```
Process myPythonSimpleArithmeticProgram = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo thisInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
thisInfo.FileName = "python";
thisInfo.Arguments = "pythonSimpleArithmetic.py";
thisInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
//thisInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
thisInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

myPythonSimpleArithmeticProgram.StartInfo = thisInfo;
myPythonSimpleArithmeticProgram.Start();

StreamWriter pySW = myPythonSimpleArithmeticProgram.StandardInput;
//python program contains functions for add and multiply
//want to use RedirectStandardOutput to have something like:
//int AddResult1 = pyInputSW.WriteLine("pyAdd, 3, 4");
pySW.WriteLine("pyAdd, 3, 4");  //this writes the answer to the python console
pySW.WriteLine("pyMultiply, 3, 4");
pySW.WriteLine("pyAdd, 5, 6");
```

Python Code:

```
import sys

def pyAdd(x,y):
   z = x + y 
   # Print to console (if desired)   
   print "Using pyAdd, the sum of %f and %f is %f" % (x, y, z)
   # Return a value back to the C# program
   return z

def pyMultiply(x,y):
   z = x * y 
   # Print to console (if desired)   
   print "Using pyMultiply, the product of %f and %f is %f" % (x, y, z)
   # Return a value back to the C# program
   return z

while True:  
   testVar = raw_input("Enter the function name: ")
   splitInput = testVar.split(",")

   if splitInput[0] == "pyAdd":  
      pyAdd(float(splitInput[1]), float(splitInput[2]))  
   elif splitInput[0] == "pyMultiply":
      pyMultiply(float(splitInput[1]), float(splitInput[2]))  
   else:
      print "Function %s not available" % splitInput[0]
```

Comment: Its long ago question, but did you solve the problem in the end? I am also trying to run Python.exe via C# code. However Imports takes a long time as Python.exe executes every time. I also want to call Python functions with different parameters once the file is loaded to avoid importing characters everytime.

Answer (score 0):

With `thisInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`

```
string output = thisInfo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
thisInfo.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Output:");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257000/is-this-possible-to-run-a-python-code-from-c-sharp-through-command-prompt)